# Laravel Form::select multiple, save an array or list of all selected fields not just last selected

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, laravel-4

Well i came across strange thing either no one noticed so far or is not possible to save from select box in laravel.

I am making a categories and those categories would be separated by type but the main problem is i wan't to use `Form::select` with `multiple` option to be able to select multiple categories but on submit laravel saves string with only last selected field, so why does `multiple` even exists if laravel saves only last selected.

Here's my code example

```
{{ Form::select('categories[1]', $platform, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::select('categories[2]', $developer, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::select('categories[3]', $publisher, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

I defined $developer, $publisher and $platform in my controller, this is basically a list of categories under specific id.

```
$platform = Category::->where('type', '=', 1)->lists('name', 'id');
```

So this returns an array of all categories for a view.

```
----------------
| name    | id |
----------------
| Windows |  1 |
----------------
| Linux   |  2 |
----------------
| MacOS   |  3 |
----------------
```

So this all works fine so far and in my web page i have a list of categories as i wanted in select box with multiple select

The problem is when it's saved it saves only string with last selected field in select box.

On submit i get this

```
["categories"]=> //This is as expected as i have 3 selects in an array
    array(2) {
      [1]=> // and this is id of first select box and category
          string(1) "3" // and this is the problem, read below please
      [2]=> // and this is id of second select box and category
          string(1) "4"
    }
```

So the problem is as you can see i get a string with number 3. that number actually represents id of last selected field, in this case i selected `MacOS` which have id of 3.

What i need to get is either this:

```
["categories"]=>
    array(2) {
      [1]=>
          string(1) "1,3"
      [2]=> 
          string(1) "4"
    }
```

Which would mean i selected `Windows` and `MacOS` and later i can get that string and explode foreach category by that id's.

Or

```
["categories"]=>
    array(2) {
      [1]=>
          array(2) {
             [0]=> 1
             [1]=> 3
          }
      [2]=> 
          array(1) {
             [0]=> 4
          }
    }
```

Any way that i can make this works?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention i am used to work with this kind of work with wordpress, it's easy to query all the data with one query and it's called multidimensional array.

I actually figured it out by trial and error, i remember for using multidimensional array in wordpress you have to define each array with brackets and it will make a tree, it's the same thing here so correct code would be:

```
 {{ Form::select('categories[1][]', $platform, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }} 
 {{ Form::select('categories[2][]', $developer, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }} 
 {{ Form::select('categories[3][]', $publisher, null, ['multiple'=>true, 'class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

and it will save it in array like this:

```
["categories"]=>
array(2) {
  [1]=>
      array(2) {
         [0]=> 1
         [1]=> 3
      }
  [2]=> 
      array(1) {
         [0]=> 4
      }
}
```